# Is there way to integrate two full page application into a single web application

Tags: angular, email, integration, mosaico

We are using Mosaico.io for email template design. Need to develop other CRUD operation functionality using Angular 7. 
Mosaico.io,email template builder is a fullpage application build using KnockoutJS . Is there any way to integrate two full page applications into a single web application.

Comment: Have a look at this article for inspiration => https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is definitely possible to integrate multiple apps into single web app.

It can be done without any extra coding effort, as long as there are no conflicts between javascript functions of the apps being merged.

Comment: https://mosaico.io/ (built upon KnockoutJS) itself is a fullpage application so is the angular. how to combine them ?